# Can't add new field after deleting fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access 2010.

Situation:

> Table reach 225 fields
>
> Delete one field (so there is 224 fields "visible" in the table)
>
> Add new field
>
> Get error 3109 "Too many fields defined."

I add and delete fields with VBA.

Add:

```
Dim dbs as Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
queryAlter = "ALTER TABLE [Table] ADD [" & [field] & "] Varchar(255)"
dbs.Execute queryAlter, dbFailOnError
dbs.Close
```

I add a field with a query because its easier for me

Delete:

```
Dim dbs as Database
Dim field as Field
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Do While dbs.TableDefs([Table]).Fields.count > 3
        Set field = dbs.TableDefs([Table]).Fields(3)
        dbs.TableDefs([Table]).Fields.Delete field.name
    Loop
dbs.Close
```

I want the first 3 fields to be stayed in the table
I don't use a query because this was faster for me. (I thought)

Answer (score 0):

In your delete code, before closing database do method `TableDefs.Refresh`

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work. I already tried that and it didn't work. I i close the database and reopen it still can't be done. But thanks

Comment: Oops I missed method objTb.Fields.Refresh. Did you try on small scale? I tried with small no of fields, and it worked as expected. If it works on small scale I am sure it would work on large scale too, because per Ms-Access Doc Tables can have fields upto 255.