# How can I delete a field from a table in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function that I am making to delete a specified field from a table that I have created in MS Access. have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266532/cant-add-new-field-after-deleting-fields) question for reference.  How could I make this delete a specified field?  Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Function removeFieldsFromIIPM(tableName As String, fieldToDrop As String)

    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim field As field

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Set field = dbs.TableDefs([tableName]).Fields(fieldToDrop)
    dbs.TableDefs([tableName]).Fields.Delete field.Name
    dbs.Close
    TableDefs.Refresh

End Function
```

Comment: May i ask you, why you dont simply drop that column with SQL? Or just try it with `dbs.TableDefs([tableName]).Fields.Delete fieldToDrop`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the DAO `TableDef` methods to drop your field, use `Database.TableDefs(tableName).Fields.Delete fieldToDrop`, as @Lokusking [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728028/how-can-i-delete-a-field-from-a-sheet-in-access-vba/38728150#comment64832158_38728028).

However I think it's easier to just execute a DDL [`ALTER TABLE` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177883(v=office.12).aspx) to drop the field:

```vb
Private Function removeFieldsFromIIPM(tableName As String, fieldToDrop As String)
    Dim strDrop As String

    strDrop = "ALTER TABLE [" & tableName & "] DROP COLUMN [" & fieldToDrop & "]"
    CurrentDb.Execute strDrop, dbFailOnError
End Function
```